# My sql parentheses when use NOT IN

Tags: mysql, notin

I use MySql, when running below query, I find it acts differently in two box, could any one help me out?

The code is here:

```
SELECT *
FROM `product` AS `e`
WHERE e.id NOT IN((SELECT `product_id` FROM `sales`))
```

In one box, it works well and returns the result. In the other box, it shows the `error: 
[Err] 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row`

And it works well in both box if remove one pair of (), as below:

```
SELECT *
FROM `product` AS `e`
WHERE e.id NOT IN(SELECT `product_id` FROM `sales`)
```

Could anyone tell me the reason, i.e. related to server setting? Can I fix this without modify the sql statements?

Answer (score 0):

The data;

```
 (SELECT `product_id` FROM `sales`)
```

is treated as the first item in the list to be used by 'NOT IN'.
This must be a single value, so you get the error because multiple rows are returned.

Comment: Have fixed the issue by upgrade MySql to a high version. thanks